# Why is parse.com PHP SDK so slow?

Tags: php, performance, time, sdk, parse-platform

I am using Parse as bridge between website (PHP) and iOS (Cocoa). When I try to create new user via PHP SDK, it takes usually more than 1sec (mostly 2sec) and same with creating regular PFObject (0.5 - 1.5sec).

My code for creating user:

```
        Debugger::timer('ps_new_user'); //start timer

        $user = new ParseUser();
        $user->set("username", $login);
        $user->set("password", $pass);
        $user->set("email", $email);
        $user->set("phone", $tel);

        try {
          $user->signUp(); //save to PARSE.com
          $elapsed_ps_new_user = Debugger::timer('ps_new_user'); // stop timer if succeeded 

        } catch (ParseException $ex) {                  
            // log all exceptions in case of error
            Debugger::log ("Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage());
            Debugger::dump($user);  
            $elapsed_ps_new_user = Debugger::timer('ps_new_user');  //stop timer if error     
        }
```

Above code takes usually 1.5sec and more in case of everything is going well.

And when I save/create new object to Parse.com with that code:

```
Debugger::timer('ps_new_obj'); //start timer

$newParseObject = ParseObject::create("Orders");
$newParseObject->set("oid", strval($oid));
$newParseObject->set("uid", strval($uid));
$newParseObject->set("date", $datum);
$newParseObject->set("name", $jmeno);
$newParseObject->set("street", $ulice);
$newParseObject->set("city", $mesto);
$newParseObject->set("zip", $psc);
$newParseObject->set("tel", $tel);
$newParseObject->set("email", $email);
$newParseObject->set("price", strval($cena));
$newParseObject->set("note", $pozn);
$newParseObject->set("text", $text);
$newParseObject->set("printed", strval($vytisknuto));

try {
    $newParseObject->save(); //save to Parse.com
    $elapsed_ps_new_obj = Debugger::timer('ps_new_obj'); //stop timer

} catch (ParseException $ex) {
        // log all exceptions
          Debugger::log ("Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage());
          Debugger::dump($newParseObject);  
          $elapsed_ps_new_obj = Debugger::timer('ps_new_obj'); // stop timer
}
```

Code above takes more than 0.5sec. Which is better than in case of creating new user, but might be better. How to speed up whole process?

Comment: Have you find solution?

Comment: I've been working with Parse.com recently and faced the same issue.
First of all, you can speed-up by using REST API instead of PHP SDK. It might be little bit faster.
However, the fastest way to connect your apps is to use your own hand-written REST API or some framework https://www.google.com/search?q=php+rest+api+framework&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=9jnDVaXuN8KYsgHUmK6QDA